# Provider Hosted App Timing out after x minutes

Tags: development, sharepoint-addin, csom, provider-hosted-app, time-out

I have a Provider hosted app which I use to enter quote data into Sharepoint Office 365. 
The Host is a MVC C# Webpage.

The action in the controllers all have a similar format like this:

```
        [SharePointContextFilter]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveSOW(int id,
        string SPHostUrl,
        bool withCostings = false)
    {
        try
        {
            var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);

            using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
            {
                var spUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;
                clientContext.Load(spUser, user => user.Title);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                var sowRepo = new SOWRepository(clientContext);
                sowRep.SaveSow(data); //pseudo code 

             }
}
```

All the actions (besides the entry point) are callled via Jquery AJAX calls.

The problem is, after X minutes when ajax calls a action that is decorated with [SharePointContextFilter] it returns a HTTP 302 (redirect to login) error.
I cant ask the usre ot re-login half way through entering a quote (which can take an hour or longer)
I have tried doing clientContext:

```
        clientContext.RequestTimeout = Timeout.Infinite;
```

with no success.

I have also tried adding a loop with Javascript to keep hitting an action in the controller with   [SharePointContextFilter]

```
    GetRefreshToken: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Refresh/RefreshToken?" + window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1),
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("Error refreshing token", data);
            }
        })
```

after a while it still sends the AJAX refresh request to appredirect.aspx

My Refresh Action is just:

```
[SharePointContextFilter]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult RefreshToken()
{
    var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);


    using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
    {
        if (clientContext != null)
        {

            return Json("Token Refreshed", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

    return Json("Token NOT Refreshed", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

}

Comment: Are you passing the SPHostUrl in the ajax request?

Comment: yes I am, like so: url: "/Quote/UpdateCOS?" + window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1),

Comment: I had this issue myself awhile back.  The problem is that the `SPContextToken` that the ACS server returns has expiry date that's just over an hour after you get it.  Since the `SharePointContext` class checks that token in the `SharePointContextFilter`, it sees that it's expired, and requires a postback to the ACS server (via the AppRedirect Url).  I ended up writing my own token helper to get the Refresh and Access tokens, and I cache the Refresh token (good for 6 months at this time) in session.

Comment: You can just modify the SharePointContext class to do the same.  I went down that road initially, but was annoyed with how they wrote the class, so decided to rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: thanks wjervis, you solved my problem. I ended up storing the refresh key in httpcontext.session and using it when contexttoken expires. i might write up a fulll answer when i finish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to wjervis for giving me the solution.
The problem was because the Oauth2 Access token was expiring and to my suprise the supplied SharePointContext classes do not rerfresh.

I hacked together a solution and blogged it here. Its definitely not the most elegant solution, but it'll point you in the right direction.

**URL REMOVED**

*update* Thanks to Microsoft closing SharePoint Public sites (which is what I used to host my blog on) I have now moved my blog to here:

https://www.sharepointpro.com.au/blog/sharepoint-provider-hosted-app-redirects-after-timeout/

Comment: I think that this problem should be reported to Microsoft and they should fix SharePointContext class, because it seems that refresh token is not used properly.

Comment: I ended up writing my own set of classes to handle the entire OAUTH dance and caching of the tokens.  If I was more confident with my abilities, I'd post them here.

Comment: this is the route I will go down eventually. half way through editing the SharePointContext I realised how much cleaner it would be to just start from scratch.

Comment: I'm unable to navigate to  http://www.sharepointpro.com.au/Blog/Post/26/Sharepoint-Provider-Hosted-App-Redirects-after-timeout asking me sign in

Comment: The link is now a 404 page

Comment: here it is http://www.sharepointpro.com.au/sharepoint-provider-hosted-app-redirects-after-timeout/

Comment: in the blog, cant find definition of `CheckIfRefreshtokenValid` method

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create some empty GET controller action with `[SharePointContextFilter]` attribute and call it periodically using JavaScript. This should prevent token expiration.

Comment: This was my first idea, unfortunately it didn't work either. Ill update the original question

Comment: @michael any update on above pls?